Remove record type
On the case object, I have removed access to a few record types against a profile, but the user is still able to create a case record with one of the record types. No special permission sets assigned for this. Any insights?
Thanks!

If you remove the access for particular record type still user has access to that record type then verify the access profile and permission set. and also check what's the default record type is assigned to user in case support setting. you might get some insights

Thanks! It was an inconspicuous  permission set that was causing it
